# How to determine the content of an Office content type of an saved Document?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, powerpoint, office-js

The documentation of [getFileAsyc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj715284.aspx) says it will always be in [(.pptx or .docx) in Office Open XML (OOXML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/office/jj220084.aspx)

Since Office 2016 this holds no longer true, if one saves the file in OpenDocument format (*.odt).

How will I get the information about the filetype? The name ends with *.odt, but in Word 2013 the name also ended with *.odt, but was transferred as *.docx

**Example:**

In following case, the binary filecontent cannot be determined:

1. Create an empty file in Word
2. Insert your TaskpaneApp
3. Safe the file as *.odt to you PC in Word
4. call getFileAsync(Compressed), and
5. get no docx but odt-content in Word 2016 with the name .odt
6. get docx-content in Word 2013 with the name .odt

For Word 2013 I fixed the problem by adding .docx to the provided name. Exactly this fix causes the Problems with Word 2016, where the file is realy a *.odt

Answer (score 0):

The input parameter of the getFileAsync method is precisely the file type you need. And this is independently on which format you saved the file.

Office.js supports 3 file types: compressed (which is docx,pptx, etc), text (plain text) and PDF.  ODT is not a file format supported in the getFileAsync Method. Check the article you referred to see what formats are supported in which Office Applications.

hope this clarification helps.

Comment: Thats wrong for some edge-cases. 
1. Create an empty file
2. Insert your TaskpaneApp
3. Safe the file as *.odt
4. call getFileAsync(Compressed), and 
4a. get no docx but odt-content in Word 2016
4b. get docx-content in Word 2013

Comment: Is this behavior a serious bug in Word 2016?

Comment: I've added a way to reproduce to my Question.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a bug, it currently is however a not supported scenario. The documentation shows it supports 3 file types, ODT is not one of them right now. Although not supported sometimes things seem to work , if it behaves differently than expected that does not make it a bug. I'm sure your feedback is noted and @juan will take it back to the team to look into adding it to the supported file types, but currently it isn't.

Comment: i am investigating within the team this issue, we should have consistent behavior among 2013 and 2016.